# How do I add a skybox / 360 panorama picture to my Archilogic 3D model?

Tags: 3d, 360-degrees, skybox, 360-panorama, archilogic

I uploaded my floor plan and received my 3D model. Now I would like to add a 360 panorama picture of the exterior, so that I can see the view when I am walking in my 3D model with the "person view" perspective .

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is currently no special feature that would allow you to simply upload a 360° panoramic picture into the Archilogic editor to get a panoramic background view.

However, you can still create and upload your own skyboxes with a little work around, if you have a bit of experience with 3d modeling software like 3DS Max, Blender or Maya. You need to map your skybox texture spherically on to a big box or sphere object.

Make sure that the polygons of this box/sphere are facing to the inside as you won't be able to see anything otherwise (the Archilogic engine only renders forward facing surfaces, while back facing surfaces are not being rendered and are therefore transparent). If you've set up your skybox like this you can export it as an .obj file. You then can import the .obj file along with the .mtl file and the textures into Archilogic by dragging and dropping the files into the editor and use the imported object as skybox.

If you want to use the light map calculation capabilities of the Archilogic editor you have to make sure that the giant box is not interfering with the light baking process by either switching off the “bake” check box of the imported skybox object or by excluding the skybox material from being used during the light map baking process.

Due to the fact that the Archilogic editor automatically compresses and down scales all imported textures to 1024x1024 pixels it may makes sense to use several materials with different textures for the same skybox in order to increase the overall resolution of the textures instead of just using a single material with a single texture file.

I hope this helps.